# Can't create a directory in the correct directory in AndroidStudio 3.0

Tags: android-studio-3.0

Am reading the Android App Dev for Dummies 3rd edition.  I've had no headaches till I reached page 92 where it asks me to

> "...create the file
>   src/main/java/com/dummies/silentmodetoggle/util/RingerHelp.java"

The only thing is that I cannot find a way to create the directory "util" in the proper directory. I tried it many ways, including doing it manually within File Explorer, but that didn't show up in my project.

According the File Explorer the directory is in the right place.  But according to AndroidStudio it is not (appears to be one level up).

It appears that there was a lower version of AndroidStudio when this book was published, yet I do appear to have the latest version of the book.

I feel as if I am asking a stupid question, I hope the answer is something obvious that is right in front of my nose.

Project structure:

[image: Project structure]